# PostgreSQL + Python: Check if record exist using variables

Tags: python, json, postgresql, variables, cherrypy

referring to [this documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/psycopg2/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers)

- Iam trying to compare *JSON* data

`jsonResponse = json.loads(dataString)` **{ 'login' : 'login' }**

`username_input = jsonResponse["login"]` **login**

- to `database` record using this call:

`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '?'" % username_input)`

- than iam calling for specific one catched and use another variable

`username_database = cur.fetchone()`

- to compare for executing loop

  ```
  if username_input == username_database:
      username_password = jsonResponse["password"]
      cherrypy.log(str(username_password))
      conn.commit()
  ```

But I am receiving None value from *database* `username_database = None`

Comment: I have user test and I am trying to execute login function with a test user. I wish to add that I am using separated HTML and Engine.

Comment: This may happen if providing username is not available in database. or, try comparing values by casting return values explicitly to string  and then strip it

Comment: I think there is something wrong with this call `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '?'" % username_input)` I guess it's not looking for what it should

Comment: What should this call do `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '?'" % username_input)`? I mean what do you need to retrieve from database?

Comment: if there is `username` row same as `login` data

Comment: You may try `cur.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '%s'", username_input)`